# How do I delete the header area in a wordpress theme and How can I change the distance between the page content and the menu bar?

Tags: css, wordpress

problems:
1. I made a website with Worpress (sorry, my coding skills are really bad) and I like to have the menu bar at the bottom of the page. Website: bo4community.de At the moment there is a grey area. How Can I remove this?
2. At my "Home" page there is no gap between the picture and the menu bar but there is a gap on the "Forum" and "Spenden" page. I created all pages with the page builder "Elementor" (also sorry for that). I forgot, how I closed the gap.

things I tried:
- Looked around in the style.css
- tried things with the page builder (padding etc.)
' Made a template
' Duplicated the "Home" page - result
- tried things with the custom css

- no sucesss yet

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space at the top of the header.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 30em){
 .site-branding {
   padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Remove the space at the bottom of the header if not in homepage.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 48em)
 .site-content {
   padding: 0 !important;
}
```